# #1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: wordpress

I am importing  database and i got an error

> 1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key PRIMARY.

i tried to upload  table individually But it gives me error for those table which have at least one row.
i don't want to delete any record of any table.

here is one table which is giving error.

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wpbeta_aff_affiliates` (
  `affiliate_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `from_date` date NOT NULL,
  `thru_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'active',
  `type` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`affiliate_id`),
  KEY `affiliates_afts` (`affiliate_id`,`from_date`,`thru_date`,`status`),
  KEY `affiliates_sft` (`status`,`from_date`,`thru_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `wpbeta_aff_affiliates`
--

INSERT INTO `wpbeta_aff_affiliates` (`affiliate_id`, `name`, `email`, `from_date`, `thru_date`, `status`, `type`) VALUES
(1, 'Direct', NULL, '2013-07-03', NULL, 'active', 'direct');
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to specify the record id (with the exception of some circumstances when you need to keep the connection between records in different tables). Try using this query:

```
INSERT INTO wpbeta_aff_affiliates (name, email, from_date, thru_date, status, type) VALUES ('Direct', NULL, '2013-07-03', NULL, 'active', 'direct');
```